# How to call Dynamics web api bound custom action without a reference of a specific entity?

Tags: dynamics-crm, microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-365, dynamics-crm-webapi, dataverse

I want to be able to call Dynamics web api action bound to some_entity without a reference to a specific entity record.

I can call the action like:

```
{{webapiurl}}/some_entity(e922f9f6-03ec-498b-8a3d-0f3fb0fe881b)/Microsoft.Dynamics.CRM.new_someAction7c68ea11a811000d3ab40d73
```

but I need to be able to call this action before the relevant record saved, so can not use an existing guid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In that case it has to be an Unbound (Global) custom Action, so you can invoke it the same way as Entity bound action and without record GUID limitation.

No other way to do it.

[image]

Comment: Thank you, after asking here, I've also decided to test this route. Thanks to you, now I know that this route will work as I need. :)